# Attribute directives

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Is there a complete list of angular attribute directives?

If not what can be considered as an attribute directive, besides the built in ngClass, ngStyle, ngModel.

I am aware that you can make one for yourself, but I need to know if there are any more built in directives, not just these three.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be asking here if I hadn't been searching the documentation for quite a while. :)

Answer (score 2):

Angular provides a list of built-in directives and gives the option to build your directives.

Feel free to read the official documentation and check all its examples.

- https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#built-in-attribute-directives
- https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives